# Replacing SUMIFS in Excel 2003

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-2003

So, I need to find an Excel 2003 substitute for =SUMIFS, which is only 2007+ (apparently).

The formula is used to generate this summary data table, from a list of revenue, where each revenue line has the field type (static, email or outreach) and the field fund (ABC, QRS and XYZ).

```
type    fund    total   count   average
static  ABC $12,390.88  171 $72.46
email   ABC $6,051.32   65  $93.10
outreach    ABC $8,835.00   138 $64.02
static  QRS $12,925.44  79  $163.61
email   QRS $9,305.44   99  $93.99
outreach    QRS $1,799.00   49  $36.71
static  XYZ $4,912.20   36  $136.45
email   XYZ $75.00  2   $37.50
outreach    XYZ $0.00   0   #DIV/0!
```

This is the formula

```
      `=SUMIFS('revenue'!G:G,'revenue'!AH:AH,Sheet2!A2,'revenue'!AI:AI,Sheet2!B2)`
```

Where G is a dollar amount, and AH and AI are matching the type or fund column.

How do i get this to work in Excel 2003?

Comment: possible duplicate of [VBA code for SUMIFS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/428414/vba-code-for-sumifs)

Comment: Possibly, but, I don't want to use VBA; I want to stick to use of core formulas. The answer below seems good though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I ended up getting past this was to create a column that combined the two columns I needed to check (ABCstatic, ABCemail, etc.) Doing it this way allowed me to use just one 'SUMIF' (using two SUMIF clauses linked together results in OR-ing of the conditions, rather than AND-ing).

`=SUMIF(Revenue!AJ2:AJ6400,Sheet2!A2, Revenue!G2:G6400)`

Answer (score 0):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(((Revenue!$AH2:$AH10=Sheet2!A2)+(Revenue!$AI2:$AI10=Sheet2!A2))*(Revenue!$G2:$G10))
```

I don't think you can use full columns with SUMPRODUCT, so you'll have to pick a range sufficiently large.  Or use some dynamic range names.

Comment: Couldn't get this to work. Instead, I just combined the fields I was using as criteria in a new column and =SUMIF'ed off of that (ABCstatic, ABCemail, etc). Seems like Excel 2003 is ok with =SUMIF singular.