# SUMIFS source code for excel 2003 AND the ability to calculate on columns

Tags: excel, vba

we are looking to find the original? source code for SUMIFS to use in out excel sheet (for both 2003 and 2007. Here is why:

- 2003 doest support the SUMIFS method
- When we do have SUMIFS we cannot utilize formulas "around" the columns (like YEAR())

For example, we want to calculate the ANSWERS that match the YEAR value of the date in cell A1 with the date values in range L:L. Now this doesnt work because we cant use YEAR(L:L) and hence we need to make another column M:M with the YEAR values from L:L

Thus we need the source to be able to upgrade the code further

> =SUMIFS(ANSWERS;L:L;"="&YEAR(A1)) <= This works
>
> =SUMIFS(ANSWERS;YEAR(L:L);"="&YEAR(A1)) <= This doesnt

Many thanks

With referenc to these questions:
[Replacing SUMIFS in Excel 2003](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3049327/replacing-sumifs-in-excel-2003)
[VBA code for SUMIFS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428414/vba-code-for-sumifs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt that you'll find the original code, which is, I imagine, C++ and part of the Excel internals. If that's correct, then it wouldn't help much, even if Microsoft gave it to you!

In general, I recommend against using `=SUMIF()`, `=SUMIFS()` and other functions that take a string to define the condition for testing: apart from anything else, I'm concerned that they're going to be slow, since my best guess is that internally they construct a string for evaluation for each value. In XL2007 (all I have available right now) at least, this turns out not to be necessarily true (see comments below).

I'm generally much happier with array functions. This, for example, should work in both Excel 2003 & 2007:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(YEAR(L:L)=YEAR(A1)),ANSWERS)
```

This gets the same answer:

```
{=SUM(IF(YEAR(L:L)=YEAR(A1),ANSWERS,0))}
```

In the latter case, you'd enter the formula without the curly braces (`{` & `}`) and confirm it using Control+Shift+Enter to tell Excel it's an array formula.

In the first example, we build a list of boolean results with `YEAR(L:L)=YEAR(A1)` and convert it into an array of 1s and 0s using the double-negative. Then `SUMPRODUCT` takes care of the rest. This version requires that `ANSWERS` has the same dimension as `L:L`, i.e. it should be the entire column (or the range in `L` should be constrained in size).

In the second, Excel will run through each entry in `L:L`. If its year matches that in A1 then the corresponding `ANSWERS` value will be used, otherwise zero. This formula seems to be more tolerant of dimension differences but I'd still be careful.

Comment: `sumproduct` is not an array formula by itself (just an alias to one), so it doesn't need to be confirmed by Ctrl+Shift+Enter... and sumproduct and array formulas in Excel 2003 need to point to regular ranges, not whole columns..

Comment: + of course sumproduct and array formulas are **[SLOWER](http://www.xldynamic.com/source/xld.SUMPRODUCT.html)** that countifs ans sumifs, the overhead that has to handle every nuance of using them is much bigger than string construcions + they have to recalculate each array for every recalculation, sumifs are better optimised to recalculate only what is needed..

Comment: Interesting. now issumif or sumproduct slow?

Comment: @deathApril - you're right on the {}, of course. Corrected. And after some tests, I'm amazed to discover that you're right on the performance thing. 100 `SUM(IF...)` on a million rows takes 1.34 sec in my very unscientific test, whereas the same with `SUMIFS` took 0.23 sec.