# How do I evaluate conditions passed into a function?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm attempting to code a `CONCATENATEIFS` function in VBA that works like `SUMIFS`, etc. Here's an example call:

`=ConcatenateIfs(",",$E$6:$E$9,$F$6:$F$9,"Something",$G$6:$G$9,">=2")`

```
Public Function ConcatenateIfs(JoinStr As String, StrRange As Range, ParamArray var() As Variant) As String

    Dim numberOfConditions As Integer
    numberOfConditions = (UBound(var) - LBound(var) + 1) / 2
    Dim tmpResult As String
    tmpResult = ""

    Dim includeItem As Boolean

    For Item = 1 To StrRange.Count
        includeItem = True
        For Condition = 1 To numberOfConditions:
            If var((Condition - 1) * 2)(Item) <> var((Condition - 1) * 2 + 1) Then
                includeItem = False
            End If
        Next Condition
        If includeItem = True And Item = 1 Then
            tmpResult = StrRange(Item)
        ElseIf includeItem = True Then
            tmpResult = tmpResult + JoinStr + StrRange(Item)
        End If
    Next Item
    ConcatenateIfs = tmpResult

End Function
```

The above function never seems to recognize that a condition has been met, meaning this part of the code is not working (i.e. that it always evaluates the inequality to True):

```
If var((Condition - 1) * 2)(Item) <> var((Condition - 1) * 2 + 1) Then
    includeItem = False
End If
```

How do I fix this so that the conditions are tested properly between an item of the criteria_range and the criteria itself? Bonus points: how do I break out of the condition loop as soon as a criteria (properly) is not met?

Comment: How are you expecting the param array with "Something",$G$6:$G$9,">=2" to work? Something like document strings would help i.e. short explanation of the function args...... You a python programmer btw?  Example input/output would help.

Comment: so for the bonus points: break loop with "exit for", break out of the whole thing: "goto".... but for the question you need to explain a little further, as QHarr mentioned, because your sample formula input doesn't match the SUMIFS format

Comment: You are comparing adjacent values and all your values in the example are different so imo inequality evaluates to true properly. Have you tested the func with identical values? BTW I can't really understand how `var((Condition - 1) * 2)(Item)` is interpreted as `var` is 1D array.

Comment: `var` is a 1D array of an even number of elements, where the even elements are criteria ranges and odd elements are criteria. So I want to evaluate the `Item`th element of the `Condition`th criteria range (found in `(Condition - 1) * 2)`) against the `Condition`th criteria (found in `(Condition -1 ) * 2) + 1`)

Comment: @AcsErno - In SUMIFS (essentially a map reduce), the first item is the implied reduction operator "+", with the first explicit item being the range to reduce. In ConcatenateIfs, the first item is an explicit reduction operator (i.e. join by ","), and my second item is the range to reduce. The rest of the signature (being criteria_range, criteria pairs) is the same.

Comment: I see. I did not notice that it was an udf. Then give a try to `var((Condition - 1) * 2)(Item) <> var((Condition - 1) * 2 + 1) .VALUE`

Comment: How is it going to perform the evaluation of ">=2" ?

Comment: @QHarr I don't know. That's the essence of the question. How does `SUMIFS` do it?

Comment: I think that is where might be falling over and so yes, for me, seemed to be the crux. Anything you write would have to be able to cope with the variability of the condition statements aswell. And yes, SUMIFS must be able to do it but I don't know how :-( Though has been touched on, without real answer,  before https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9976325/sumifs-source-code-for-excel-2003-and-the-ability-to-calculate-on-columns   The potential C++ construction of strings being way beyond a nice neat vba answer.

Comment: And I am guessing you already saw this and other linked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428414/vba-code-for-sumifs?noredirect=1&lq=1